# Jquery Dropdown select update input field on cloned forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

So i have a form that I'm dynamically cloning with Jquery .clone. So when a user selects a choice in the drop down menu depending on what the value is, it will update a text box with a value automatically while still allowing the user to change they value if they don't agree with whats there. The code that i have updates the fields but it is updating all input fields with the id i specify i have tried referencing the parent item then looking for the next input box with an id. I'm not sure if maybe I'm processing this wrong in my head. Any help would be appreciated.

My form code:

```
  <div id="test">
        <span>
            <label>
                File Type:
               <select id="book_type")
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option value="2">2</option>
                   <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <label>
              Book ID<input type="text" id="book_id" name="book_id" />  
            </label>
            <label>
                Tray Number:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tray_number" required id="tray_number" class="tray_nu" placeholder="Required" value="" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Comments: <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" value="" />
                <input type="button" id="delBttn" name="delBttn" disabled value="X" />
             </label>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="new_section"></div>
<input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Another Book" />
```

My Copy Code (Which works great) and my change code(this is not working properly)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addbutton").click(function(){
        var clone = $("#test").clone(true).insertBefore("#new_section:last");
        clone.find('[id*="delBttn"]').attr('disabled', false);
        clone.find('[id*="book_type"]').val('');
        clone.find('[id*="comments"]').val('');
    });

$("#delBttn").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest("span").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#book_type").change(function(){
    var book_type =  $(this).val();
    if(book_type === '2'){
        $('span').parent().find("#tray_number").val('2');
    }
});

}); //end of DOM
```

So now when you click on the dropdown box and change it to option 2, its filling all boxes with the value of option 2. I'm trying to get it to only change the value of tray number in the same row as the drop down box.

Comment: You have issues with multiple IDs.  See my answer which resolves those issues as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are selecting all spans on the page in your change handler. To just get the span that is parent of the changed dropdown, you can use `$(this)` to get the changed `<select>` element and use `.closest('span')` to traverse up the DOM tree and select the first span that is a parent of that select.

```
$("#f_types").change(function(){
    var book_type =  $(this).val();
    if(book_type === '2'){
        $(this).closest('span').find("#tray_number").val('2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few issues with your HTML and JavaScript, which I've fixed in the example below.  The biggest issue was the fact that you will end up with duplicate IDs, and you cannot have more than one element with the same ID.

After changing the IDs for classes, use this code to find the closest parent with class 'test', then find the child with class 'tray_nu' and set its value.

```
$(this).closest('span').find(".tray_nu").val('2');
```

**Full Example:**

HTML:

```
<div class="test"> <span>
    <label>File Type:
        <select class="book_type">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label>Book ID
        <input type="text" class="book_id" name="book_id" />
    </label>
    <label>Tray Number:&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="tray_number" required class="tray_nu" placeholder="Required" value="" />
    </label>
    <label>Comments:
        <input type="text" name="comments" class="comments" value="" />
        <input type="button" class="delBttn" name="delBttn" disabled value="X" />
    </label>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="new_section"></div>
<input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Another Book" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addbutton").click(function () {
        var clone = $(".test").clone(true).insertBefore("#new_section:last");
        clone.attr('class', 'testnew');
        clone.find('[class*="delBttn"]').attr('disabled', false);
        clone.find('[class*="book_type"]').val('');
        clone.find('[class*="comments"]').val('');
    });

    $(".delBttn").click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest("span").remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".book_type").change(function () {
        var book_type = $(this).val();
        if (book_type === '2') {
            $(this).closest('span').find(".tray_nu").val('2');
        }
    });

}); //end of DOM
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/mv9y6xrL/

Comment: there is a bug in your code when you click add another book more than twice, it is cloning all the existing dom.

Comment: change the classname on cloned dom from test to anything else.. i think it should work then

Comment: But you haven't fixed the issues. He's still cloning a section that has multiple IDs ending up in the same situation he was in before. You claim "you cannot have more than one element with the same ID", but your working "fixed" example shows that this is not the case.

Comment: The issues are fixed now.  I missed a couple of IDs, and those are resolved in the updated example and fiddle.